# React, how to add external script and make its functions available?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I wonder how I would add an external script to an `React` application and make its functions available. Let's take this script https://www.cssscript.com/confetti-falling-animation/

In a "not-react-application" I would add it like this in my `DOM`

```
<script src="confetti.js"></script>
```

and then call it's functions like this

```
startConfetti();
```

or

```
stopConfetti();
```

However, this does not work in `React`. I know that I can add a `<script />` tag like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const script = document.createElement('script');

    script.src = './confetti.js';
    script.async = true;

    document.body.appendChild(script);

    return () => {
        document.body.removeChild(script);
    }
}, []);
```

But this does not make the functions `startConfetti()` or `stopConfetti()` available. They are `undefined`.

How would I add the script and its functionalities in a `React` App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the script in `index.html`'s head tag, like so (with the correct path to the JavaScript file):

```
<script src="confetti.js"></script>
```

Then in your React component, you could get it with the help of `window` object, this way:

```
const startConfetti = window.startConfetti;
startConfetti();
```

Comment: @Stophface — You need to use a URL to your script. You can't use a URL hosted by the  react dev server. That doesn't deal with serving static files.